# Subsequent function calls using previous values

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, mobile-webkit

**CSS**

```
body{  
  background:#000;   
  width:320px;  
 height:480px;  
}  

.view  
{  
   width:320px;   
   height:480px;   
   background:#0066CC;  
   overflow:hidden;  
   visibility:hidden;  
   position:absolute;   
   left:0;top:0;  
   z-index:8; 
}  

.o{background:#FF9900;}   

.main{ visibility:visible;}  

.swapper {
  width:640px;  
 height:480px;   
  overflow:hidden;   
  position:absolute;  
   left:0;top:0;  
  visibility:hidden;  
  z-index:9;
 }  
 .on{position:static; float:left; visibility:visible;}  

 .btn {height:50px; width:125px; font-size:16px; background:#000; color:#FFF;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function $(id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function clean()
{
        alert("1");
        ele = $("swapper");
        ele.removeEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd" , clean , true);
        //ele.style.webkitTransition = "height 0s";
        ele.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px,0,0)";
        ele.zIndex = "7";
        ele.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //currentView = nextView;

}
function show(current , next)
{

    alert(current+ "    " + next);
    //nextView = next;
    s = $("swapper");
    s.innerHTML = "";
    nel = $(next);
    cel = $(current);
    v1 = cel.cloneNode(true);v2 = nel.cloneNode(true);

    v1.id = "v1";  v1.onclick = ""; v1.className += " on";
    v2.id = "v2";  v2.onclick = ""; v2.className += " on";

    s.appendChild(v1);  s.appendChild(v2);
    s.style.webkitTransition = "-webkit-transform 1s ease";

    s.style.zIndex = "9";
    s.style.visibility = "visible";
    nel.style.visibility = "visible";
    cel.style.visibility = "hidden";



    //s.style.left = "0px";
    s.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd" , clean, true);
    s.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(-320px,0,0)";
    //setTimeout(clean , 1000);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="swapper" class="swapper"></div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="set1">
        <div id="main" class="view main o"><h1>1</h1><span class="btn" onclick="show('main','2');">Next</span></div>
        <div id="2" class="view"><h1>2</h1><span class="btn" onclick="show('2','3');">Next</span></div>
        <div id="3" class="view o"><h1>3</h1><span class="btn" onclick="show('3','4');">Next</span></div>
        <div id="4" class="view"><h1>4</h1><span class="btn" onclick="show('4','main');">Next</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

i am trying to create sliding panels , but this javascript function when called is executed with previous values once and then with the new values.

Comment: I haven't run your code, but note that when cloning an element, listeners added inline are preserved - but listeners added by *addEventListener* will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks , the problem is solved , now i have another problem , the panes are not animating on iphone 2g 3.1.3. its working fine on iphone4 and ipod4

Answer (score 1):

This kind of menu is called a horizontal accordion. There are countless simple plugins for jQuery -- why reinvent the wheel? Many examples available:

**Examples**

- [haccordion, a simple horizontal accordion plugin for jQuery](http://letmehaveblog.blogspot.com/2007/10/haccordion-simple-horizontal-accordion.html)
- [jQuery Simple Horizontal Accordion](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-horizontal-accordion/)
- [30 jQuery Accordion Menus, Tutorials And Best Examples](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/)

Comment: this is not accodion. its more like a carasel . i am doing it for iphone webapp , this is a simple script , jquery and then the plugin overhead. i just have to fix this one little problem.

Comment: It's hard to see from your code exactly what effect your looking for. Something like these perhaps? http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

Comment: yes something like that . i have made the code work , RobG advice worked. but now the problem is its not working on iphone2g

Comment: iphone 2g browser probably doesn't support CSS3 animations.

Comment: it does support css3 and webkit translate3d , but one of the properties that i m using to manipulte the animation is probably not supported by iphone2g